# How can I make my website more mobile friendly?

Tags: mobile, mobile-safari

I am looking for advice how to show my website on a mobile device as appears and loads correctly on a PC and iPad but too big on mobile:

Here is one of my websites:
https://amtgridiron.neocities.org/bflers/

Here is the CSS code link:
https://amtgridiron.neocities.org/bflers/bfl.css

I like having the content in the middle as I think it looks great but on a mobile the content appears too big.

Other pages:

https://amtgridiron.neocities.org/bflers/bflchampionshipgame.htm

I need pages with tables to appear on the website all together to show chronological results but still content is too big, any tips would be greatly appreciated?

Look forward to hearing from you

Alex

Answer (score 0):

I think that using a framework like **[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/)** in your case is going to make your life way easier.

In case you do not know what Bootstrap is, it is a CSS framework to develop **responsive** and **mobile-first** applications, this means that you would be able to design your web for both mobile and desktop devices.

This can be achieved as well in conventional CSS, by using media queries, so you are able to design the web for mobile devices by picking the max-width. Here is a little example:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 .facet_sidebar {
   display: none;
  }
}
```

In this case, the website would not display the sidebar if the max-width is less than 600px.

You can use this in your web so you are able to adjust the cols and rows, for example.

Comment: Hi @sromeu thanks for your help. I have done some research and I look at the templates but can’t see how I can get my table (https://amtgridiron.neocities.org/bflers/bflchampionshipgame.htm) to be mobile friendly as it is still too big for the screen and only shows two columns out of 4.  Any ideas?  

I suppose I need to get the table to appear correctly and build the content around it

Comment: @user3756889 If the answer has been helpful and it has fixed your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer, I am here to help you with any other thing you want! Thank you and glad I was able to help.

Comment: Hi @sromeu thanks for your help. I have done some research and I look at the templates but can’t see how I can get my table (https://amtgridiron.neocities.org/bflers/bflchampionshipgame.htm) to be mobile friendly as it is still too big for the screen and only shows two columns out of 4.  Any ideas?  

I suppose I need to get the table to appear correctly and build the content around it

Comment: Please load my website on your phone and tell me if there is a fix?

The home page (https://amtgridiron.neocities.org/bflers) is also how I want it to look, do you have any code to redevelop the page to suit my needs but is in keeping with the style?

Comment: @user3756889 I think that you should try to recreate the design that you already have with Bootstrap, so you are able to do both the desktop and mobile view.

Comment: I’ve managed to do a fix https://amtgridiron.neocities.org/austrianbowl/greycup.htm but not technical but fits all devices